# Objective C - Google Search Ads request (GADSearchRequest) memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, ads, google-search

I use GADSearchRequest in my app and this line of code causes leaks in Instrument:

```
GADSearchRequest *adRequest = [[[GADSearchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];  
UIColor *backGroundSolid = UIColorFromRGB([gsa.backgroundColor hexIntValue]);  
**[adRequest setBackgroundSolid:backGroundSolid];**  //This line cause leaks??????
```

Do you know how to fix it or it is a bug in GADSearchRequest class?

Comment: Is it working for u?.. I am not able to see any difference in ad when I set "backGroundSolid" property

Answer (score 0):

So I use:

```
[adRequest setBackgroundSolid:[backGroundSolid autorelease]];
```

in my code, I see no leaks in Instruments, but I get **"Object sent -autorelease too many times"** when I analyze the app.

I published the app to AppStore and the app works fine, no complaints, so I think this will fix the problem, I hope Google will fix this bug soon.